# spread in setState of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I saw this in somewhere and I'm confused. I've never do thing this way, what it does actually?

```
doSomething = index => {
    const tempState = this.state
    tempState.keys.push(index)

    this.setState({
      ...tempState
    })
  }
```

Comment: it creates a new object with all the properties of the tempState object; a shallow clone

Comment: you shouldn't mutate state like that...

Comment: What is does it mutate the state directly, which you shouldn't ever do. It should use the spread operator when making the first copy of the state. If you specifically mean the spread part, well there's plenty info out there on what spread 
operator does for objects/arrays.

Comment: @dandavis so what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: @Jayce444 so what is the right solution? I still in the es5 stage

Answer (score 0):

```
const tempState = this.state
```

The above assigns to `tempState` a reference to the state object

```
tempState.keys.push(index)
```

`tempState` has a property of keys that holds a reference to an array and push is called on the array to add `index` to the array

```
this.setState({
  ...tempState
})
```

`this.setState` is called and a new copy of the state is passed into `setState`.
The spread operator is basically copying the content of the old state into a new object.

Comment: how to refactor it?

Answer (score 0):

The above implementation isn't the perfect one and should be improved so that you aren't mutating the original state object.

```
doSomething = index => {
    const tempState = this.state  // assing reference of state to tempState
    tempState.keys.push(index) // push a value to `keys` property value within state. Note that Javascript object assignment works by reference and hence this will actually mutate the state object

    this.setState({ 
      ...tempState
    }) // call setState to update state and pass the cloned version of tempState using spread syntax as the new state values
  }
```

Although the above implementation clones the value before setState, its incorrect since it should clone the value before any update is made into it

```
doSomething = index => {
    const keys = [...this.state.keys]
    keys.push(index)

    this.setState({
      keys
    })
  }
```

However since you use ES5, in order to clone the value, you can make use of concat to update the keys array using functional setState like

```
doSomething = index => {

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      keys: prevState.keys.concat([index])
    }))
  }
```

I hope the above answer provides an insight into the explanation that you were looking for